# Postgres select records first seen yesterday

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to select all records that were first seen in the last day along with some other aggregates but I can't figure it out as aggregates aren't allowed in the where clause.

This was my attempt:

```
SELECT  m.m_id, 
        m, 
        SUM(count) AS e_count, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(c_code)) AS c_count 
FROM e 
  LEFT JOIN m ON e.m_id = m.m_id 
WHERE   MIN(e_t::date) = current_date - INTERVAL '1' day 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

I also had a play with an sub query but didn't get it to work. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the logic in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT m.m_id, m, SUM(count) AS e_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(c_code)) AS c_count 
FROM e LEFT JOIN
     m
     ON e.m_id = m.m_id 
GROUP BY 1 
HAVING MIN(e_t::date) = current_date - INTERVAL '1' day 
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

However, you might find that filtering *before* the aggregation is more efficient.  You can do that with a `WHERE` clause and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.m_id, m, SUM(count) AS e_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(c_code)) AS c_count 
FROM e LEFT JOIN
     m
     ON e.m_id = m.m_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM e e2
                  WHERE e2.m_id = e.m_id AND
                        e_t::date < current_date - INTERVAL '1' day 
                 )
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```